# Extract first argue from column with T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, split, sql-server-2012

I need to extract the first argument: `"\PATH\TO\PACKAGE"` from the string below:

```
/SQL "\PATH\TO\PACKAGE" /SERVER "0.0.0.0,0000" /USER usr /PASSWORD "passw" /DECRYPT pass2 /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E
```

which is a column stored at SQL Server `msdb.sysjobsteps.command`

Is there a way to do it by using Regex or Spliting it by blank spaces?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have regular expressions. It's far easier to parse text on the client anyway. SQL, the language, is terrible at text manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the **one** example we have, a couple of `CHARINDEX`s a little bit of simple string manipulation gets the job done:

```sql
DECLARE @YourString nvarchar(500) = N'/SQL "\PATH\TO\PACKAGE" /SERVER "0.0.0.0,0000" /USER usr /PASSWORD "passw" /DECRYPT pass2 /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E';

SELECT LEFT(STUFF(V.YourString,1,CI1.I,''),CI2.I-CI1.I-1)
FROM (VALUES(@YourString))V(YourString)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',V.YourString)))CI1(I)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CHARINDEX(' /',V.YourString,CI1.I)))CI2(I);
```

If parameters don't change position, then you can build a more robust solution.